# Cyclic machine that converts work into heat

Tags: thermodynamics

I wondering if is possible to build a cyclic ideal machine that converts the given work completely into heat. It would be the opposite of a thermal machine.

I am interested in this question because books on this subject says that you cannot build a perfect thermal machine but I think is also impossible to build a perfect machine that converts all the given work in heat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The key word is **completely** and the answer is no. You can convert *most* of the work to heat, but you'll never get a 100% conversion.

Comment: Hi MaxW, then the problem that there is not a perfect machine is not related with the Thermodynamics second law as books very often say. I think it is impossible, in general, to create a cyclic thermodynamic machine that transforms completely work into heat or vice-versa, right?

Answer (score 1):

Building a machine that turns work into heat is trivial. In fact, it's a great challenge to produce as little "waste" heat as possible. [The experiment that proved that heat is a type of energy transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equivalent_of_heat) was a machine that does just what you're asking. Similarly, electric stoves take energy that could power a device that does mechanical work and turns it all into heat.

If the goal is to get as much heat as possible, though, you can do even better than turning all of the work into output heat. If you arrange a [heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) you can use the energy to extract heat from an outside source, getting more heat where you want it than if you'd just turned the energy into heat directly, but more slowly.

Comment: Thank you, Sean. But my question is about a cyclic process. Can you imagine a cyclic process that converts all the given work into heat? For example, a sequence of thermodynamics process in Pressure/Volume diagram that converts all the given work into heat and returns to initial point.

Comment: Sure - take two Carnot engines. Setup one to extract heat from the hot reservoir, do work, and expel heat to the cold. Setup the other to run as a refrigerator that takes the work from the first engine, extracts heat from the hot reservoir, and expels it to the cold.

Comment: Sean, I din't understad. Is his coupling of Carnot engine be a cyclic machine that converts completely work in heat? I don't think so.

Comment: What do you mean by perfect? If you mean can be run reversibly, then you are right, no reversible engine can just intake heat from a hot source and exhaust it to a cold source. Because were that the case, you could simply reverse it and make a Clausius 2nd law violator. The moment you add irreversible processes, though, the efficiency of the engine drops, potentially to zero.

Comment: Hi Sean, I am interested in your analysis of a cyclic process that converts totally (perfect) work into heat. I think it is not possible to build a machine (based on a cyclic thermodynamic process) that converts 100% of work into heat. I think this is very strange because books very often say that the impossibility of a perfect is due to the second thermodynamics law but even for a cyclic process that converts work in heat is impossible to have 100 % efficiency. Thank you.

Comment: @Sean Lake is right; the addition of an irreversible process to a cyclic engine is all that is required.  Just consider a flywheel with friction on the axle; the wheel motion is cyclic (returns again and again to its initial position).

Comment: Here's a really simple engine that does no work and transfers heat from hot to cold. Take a cylinder filled with an ideal gas at some pressure and volume in thermal equilibrium with a cold heat bath at $T_c$. Break contact with the cold reservoir and put it in contact with a hot reservoir at $T_h > T_c$ and let it heat isometrically (constant volume heating) until it reaches $T_h$. Shift it back to the cold reservoir. That's a closed cycle that can be made quasistatic, though not reversible, that does no work and transfers heat from hot to cold.